Get characters between comma and space
I have a field that looks like this.  CARREON,DAVID J. I want to put them in individual fields.
CARREON AS Middlename
DAVID AS Firstname
J AS Middle initial

I think you will want to use a string parsing/splitting function, but those are not standardized.  Each version/vendor of sql has their own.  Which specific sql are you using?

Do you mean that you have a column with CARREON,DAVID J., and you want to use that string to populate three other columns?

Are you sure all of the names are in that exact format?  i.e. nobody has a two-part first name such as "Anne Marie"?  And everybody has a middle initial?

Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question. At the very least, you need to add a tag for the RDBMS you're using, as functionality and syntax varies widely between them. It's extremely difficult to help you when you don't provide one of the most important details.
